# Experiences with Scala swing, how does it add to what's already available in Java swing? Are there any challenges?

Tags: java, swing, scala, user-interface

I've just started learning the Scala language with the intent of using Scala swing to develop GUI applications.

I'm just curious as to some of the experiences other people have had with Scala swing and in what ways is it better than Java?

For example, the main arguments I've heard for the advantages of Scala swing are:
1) That it wraps java swing, so many of the features available in Java swing can be used
2) It simplifies event handling.. no more of those pesky anonymous classes and remembering which methods to override as in Java
3) You can make use of the powerful Scala collections library
4) More powerful graphics drawing (edit: not really true, sorry I'm a beginner :P)

I say nothing beats experience though, so to those who have used Scala swing for a while.. what are your experiences? Are there any benefits I didn't list up there? Are there any challenges (or some things it doesn't do as well as Java swing?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happened to look yesterday at an older project of mine which contained a lot of things migrated from a previous Java version of that project. At the time I was not fully convinced of Scala Swing, so it still used javax.swing (in Scala). Seeing that code, it struck me what a huge mistake it was not to use Scala Swing here.

Scala Swing has the huge advantage of making the code *much* less verbose and easier to read and write. Items 1, 2 and 3 on your list absolutely apply. I don't understand No. 4 "more powerful graphics drawing", though. Scala Swing's wrapper components have a hook that allows you to override their own `paintComponent` methods, and drawing code will be correctly injected. But other than getting a `java.awt.Graphics2D` instead of the `java.awt.Graphics` which you must typically cast in Java, I see no advantage here.

Scala Swing's design was mostly done well, but there are a few things I don't like. First of all, there are a couple of missing things, which means that for any non-trivial GUI, you will have to resort to calling into the `peer` javax.swing layer from time to time. No big deal, but aesthetically unsatisfying. There are a few projects to amend this, e.g. [ScalaSwingContrib](https://github.com/benhutchison/ScalaSwingContrib) and [SwingPlus](https://github.com/Sciss/SwingPlus).

Scala Swing typically makes the assumption that your GUI is simple. For example, there are often no proper wrappers for the underlying widget models. Take for example `ListView`—you create it with a static list of items. There is no concept of a dynamic list model which drives the view. If you want that, you have to deal with the peer again.

The second thing I don't like is that the type design of the reactor approach is very dynamic and not quite type safe. I would have preferred a different approach which uses sealed traits for the events published by a widget, so your reaction `PartialFunctions` can be type checked. A related problem is that with type parametrised widgets, e.g. `ListView[A]`, there is no way to have events parametrised in `A` (hypothesised: `ListView.ItemSelected[A](v: ListView[A], elem: A)`). For `Table`, not even the effort was made to use type parameters.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to anyone who writes desktop applications in Scala to go and use Scala Swing and not javax.swing.